# Jquery getScript or ajax combined with php flush

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I need to list items upon search. 
Instead of using some kind of loading sign, infinite progress or whatever while the serverside php script finishes it job, I would like to have the results appear as soon as they have been found serverside.

PHP side seams quite easy to perform just a fake 10x result (server.php):

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
$i = 0;
while($i < 10)
    {
        ?>
        $('#resultZone-13').append('<div class="fileline">someresult</div>');
        <?
        flush();ob_flush(); 
        usleep(200000); //0,2s
        $i++;

    }
```

clientside, I would have hoped the getScript would work, but it didn't, this is what I have:

```
$.post('server.php',{}, function(data) 
    {
    },"script");
```

but this combination waits for the serverside script to fully complete before executing the 10 jquery commands. How can I make JQuery execute the commands as soon as they are received?

The only idea I have would be to load an offscreen iframe and ask to load the server.php page inside this iframe, but then, I'm stuck inside this iframe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got this to work after several days off.. (Im a new dad!)
Basically this is the way to do it:

Create an invisible iframe on the document and load the remote php file in it. This php file can flush some javascript content to this iframe, this is the only way i've found to let it display it sequentially.

For instance, I got this test running:

```
<?
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
echo '<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>';
$i = 0;
while($i < 10)
    {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(window.parent.document).find('#subfolder13').append('<div class="folderline"><div class="closedfolder" style="margin-left:48px;"></div>Pecq</div>')

        </script>
        <?
        flush();ob_flush(); 
        usleep(200000); //0,2s
        $i++;

    }
?>
```

I don't care about the heavy query load at the begining as this is the exact same file as the caller  frame, so in 99% cases this file is freshly cached. If really needed this could be plain javascript, doesn't changes the idea behind this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, you will either have to implement [socket.io](http://socket.io/) or use [$.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) instead.

Try this :

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = 'test.php';
$('head').append(s);
```

Comment: Even when I use $.getScript  the script is executed once the 2 second php script is finished...

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't. (it's executed after server.php page generation)